# Getting error messages in github

Tags: git, github, terminal, file-transfer

I was trying to push a markdown document to github and i got this error when i tried to commit the file:

`Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
nothing to commit, working tree clean`

I solved the error with:

`git reset HEAD^ --soft`

then tried to push with:

`git push -u origin master`

and got another error after trying to push the document, error:

`! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)`

i tried to solve this error with:

`git pull origin master`

but when i tried pushing the document again i got the error message

`Everything up-to-date`

I can't seem to figure out where to go from here.

Answer (score 2):

Have you staged the file?

If you run `git status` do you see something like this?

```
On branch master
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    my_file.md

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

You need to run something like `git add my_file.md` before `git commit`.

Comment: I ran git status and it gave me this message `On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
nothing to commit, working tree clean` and i also `git add .` the file before `git commit`

Comment: That means you don't currently have any changes to that markdown file on your file system. Are you trying to add this markdown file to the repository for the first time, or just add changes?

Comment: I am adding it for the first time i tried several times before and it sent  a .DS_store commit in my repo. I deleted those and i am trying to resend the right file.

Comment: Based on the result of your `git status`, either the file doesn't exist for you in the folder where the git repository resides, or you've already added it to the repository, or it is being ignored by your `.gitignore` file.

Comment: Please how do i check if it is being ignored? It is not in my repository, when i run `ls` it shows the file so the file exists, so my conclusion is that it is being ignored.

Comment: I ran `git - check ignore  -v filename` and it is not returning anything

Comment: Try `git check-ignore -v my_file.md`, if it returns nothing then it is not being ignored. It sounds like you may have already committed the file to the repository.

Comment: Yea i was able to push it as an empty directory but now i am having problems writing to it, so it's empty. So i am just trying to add text to the folder now and having issues.

Comment: It created a submodule trying to make that a normal repository. Never mind i will just have to figure out this new set of issue myself thank you!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure the file is actually not there on github but there in your working directory.

If you can see the file with `ls` and `git status` says your branch is up-to-date with `origin/master`, try what happens if you create a new file and try to add that for testing:

```
touch mytestfile.txt
git add mytestfile.txt
```

`git status` should now show the file as newly added.

```
git commit -m "this is a test commit"
```

`git status` should now say `On branch master. nothing to commit, working tree clean`.

`git push` should now upload your file to github.

Does this work? If yes, try adding your file with a different filename and look if you have accidentally ignored it by listing it in a `.gitignore` file.

By the way:

> Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'. nothing to commit,
>   working tree clean
>
> I solved the error with:
>
> git reset HEAD^ --soft

`git commit` did probably not actually create a commit, because there was "nothing to commit". This means that `git reset HEAD^ --soft` reset you one commit further back than you intended. You could not push that because that was literally an old version - I can't test currently whether this szenario would actually give you the error `non-fast-forward`, but either it does or you commited a change locally in between.